# Way to use :not to keep CSS from being applied to one single page id?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, margin

I come to you with a seemingly quick fix, but it's turned out tougher than expected.

So what I'd like to do is apply the following CSS below to all my site's pages, EXCEPT for one: .page-id-145. I've tried using section:not(.page-id-145) attached at the start of the following code, but it ends up messing up my other pages, while fixing the page I need. How can I simply JUST exclude the following code from the page I want, without messing up the other pages? I specifically want the last two lines (margin and float) to go away on page id 145.

```
#wrapper #main-content {
  padding: 28px 28px 10px;
  width: 720px;         
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
```

---

The code I am working with up top applies to my theme CSS in Wordpress. Here is more CSS that I think could be relevant, which also includes what is above.

```
#header,
#main-content,
#wrapper-footer {
  float: none;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;        
}
#wrapper #main-content {
  padding: 28px 28px 10px;
  width: 720px;         
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: none;
}
#content {
  float: none;
  width: 750px;       
}
```

And here is the specific HTML of the page in question (which is funnily enough, a single iframe):

```
<object data=https://rateyourmusic.com/list/wbhyatt/the_best_albums_ive_ever_heard/8/ width="960" height="900"> <embed src=https://rateyourmusic.com/list/wbhyatt/the_best_albums_ive_ever_heard/8/ width="960" height="900"> </embed></object>
```

Comment: So the element you add the class `page-id-145` is a `section`? Could you please add the HTML to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try resetting each style for `.page-id-145`. Maybe something like this:

```
.page-id-145 {
  margin: unset;
  float: unset;
}
```

If the unset value doesn't do anything, the the `inherit` or `initial` values. You can read about the differences between these values [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cascading/values.html).

Comment: unfortunately none of those options appear to work :( I tried inherit, initial, and unset, as well as with !important qualifiers to no avail. I'm not sure why this won't work - it seems like it should.

Comment: Could you add your HTML? It would be helpful.

Comment: I just added some more CSS from my theme page in Wordpress that may help and/or influence the page in question. I also added the HTML I have for the page. Thank you so much for all the help.